# SQL - SUMMING CASE/WHEN Continued

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum, case-when

I just asked a question linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37865838/sql-summing-case-when-values-from-different-fields/37866376#37866376) about Summing from a CASE/WHEN query. Part of my question was answered, which leads to another question.

See picture below:
  [image]

I have three fields, item_no, comp_item_no and Overhead. The comp_item_no is a list of component items for the item_no field. This means that items 00011PP, 00011PPX and 00011X, are at least partially created from item 00011.

Items 00011 and 00011S are made up from item ST1FJP91 which has a NULL overhead cost.

Unfortunately, the Overhead value displayed in the field does not take component items into consideration. Instead of the $23.44 displayed for item_no 00011PP, the true Overhead value would be $23.44 + $16.02, or $39.46. That is because item_no 00011 was at least partially used in creating item_no 00011PP and it's Overhead value needs to reflect that.

I need to find a way to SUM these overhead values to  include their respective component items, but I cannot find a feasible solution. Here is my query showing the rest of the story:

```
SELECT 'Overhead' = Sum(CASE
                      WHEN vac_type IN ( 'A01', 'AD0', 'ADX', 'AO1',
                                                      'CI0', 'DO1', 'DP9', 'O20',
                                                      'PWO', 'TO1', 'WO1', 'WO2' ) 
THEN ( Cost_values)
                      ELSE NULL
                    END),
   item_no,
   comp_item_no
FROM   Table_1       
GROUP BY item_no,
         comp_item_no
```

Just so you know, vac_type is an identifier for different Values, meaning when vac_type IN ( 'A01', 'AD0', 'ADX', 'AO1', 'CI0', 'DO1', 'DP9', 'O20',PWO', 'TO1', 'WO1', 'WO2' ), then the Values are Overhead

Comment: jeez, you just keep adding more and more details to your question. Can't you just use `comp_item_no` in the `SELECT` and remove `item_no` from it and the `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Including an image with truncated column names and values doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need to sum the overhead for each item.  Then you need to add in the overhead for the related items.  If so:

```
with toh as (
      select t1.item_no, t1.comp_item_no,
             (sum(case when vac_type in ( . . . ) then overhead else 0 end) as overhead
      from table_1 t1
     )
select toh.item_no, toh.comp_item_no, 
       (toh.overhead + sum(toho.overhead)) as overhead
from toh left join
     toh toho
     on toh.comp_item_no = toho.item_no
group by toh.item_no, toh.comp_item_no, toh.overhead;
```